# Select table data based on value in CSS

Tags: css, html-table, css-selectors

How can I select a table data based on value in CSS ?

I am trying like below:

```
#users tbody tr td[value=1]
```

Comment: Can you provide an example HTML of the element you are trying to select?

Comment: The selector `[value=1]` will works with an attribute in your HTML, not the value itself ; i.e `<td value="1">blah blah blah</td>` will work, but not `<td>1</td>`

Comment: Thanks @PierreLeBot for your reply. I need `<td>1</td>` this one. What can I do ? Thanks

Comment: @abuabu That's not the value. That's text inside the element. You will need to use javascript.

Comment: Can I use it like `td[text=1]` ?

Comment: As told before, the rule you want to use in CSS has to reflect an attribute, which is found in the markup. The text value of an element is another thing, and not an attribute. So the answer is « no »